# Ascii Art Animation in Browser

Tags: javascript, animation, browser, ascii-art

I want to animate Ascii Art in the Browser.
The Ascii Art should be loaded via a text file. There are many libraries which convert but I have found none, which actually animates it.

By animation I mean a typewriter animation that speeds up over time and changes the 'zoom factor' so that the whole image is visible in the viewport at the end.

Hopefully anyone knows a libary for my problem.

Comment: Could you show us the code you have so far, including an actual ASCII text file of the sort you are interested in and what do you want to happen on devices with small screens?

Comment: Since I am looking for a libary I have no relevant code yet. [Ascii Art txt file](http://txt.do/185fj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling SO doesn't like library recommendations, and actually I haven't found one, so here's some basic code to get you started.

It sets the typing speed to the old Teletype 10 chars per second and of course that can be changed, and an acceleration function can be added when you know what you want for that. Note: the txt file needs to be on the same domain to prevent CORS problems.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Typewriter print</title>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
      font-family: Courier, monospace;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <input id="file" type="text" value="" placeholder="Filename" />
    <button onclick="loadFile()">Click to draw the file</button>
    <div id="picture"></div>
  </div>
  <script>
    let file = '';
    let reader = new XMLHttpRequest();

    function loadFile() {
      file = document.getElementById('file').value;
      reader.open('get', file, true);
      reader.onreadystatechange = draw;
      reader.send(null);
    }

    function draw() {
      if (reader.readyState == 4) {
        const picture = document.getElementById('picture');
        picture.innerHTML = '';
        let str = reader.responseText;
        let chs = str.split('');
        //set as the typing speed in characters
        //per second 10 is the old teletype speed
        let chsPerSec = 10;
        let i = 0;

        function reveal() {
          if (i < chs.length) {
            let nextch = chs[i];
            if (nextch.charCodeAt(0) == 10) {
              nextch = '<br>';
            } else if (nextch.charCodeAt(0) == 32) {
              nextch = '<span style="color:transparent;">.</span>';
            }
            picture.innerHTML = picture.innerHTML + nextch;
            setTimeout(reveal, Math.floor(1000 / chsPerSec));
            i++;
          }
        }
        reveal();
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```